# Como usar getClass.GetName

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo y voy a crear un menu el problema radica en como hacer que se hace para que cuando nos referamos a un perro se veo lo de sacar a pasear y cuando sea un pajaro se vea sacar a volar

```
    Animal prueba = new Perro;
    System.out.println("Bienvenido al Tamagotchi Estas en los años 90!!!!");
    System.out.println("Escribe una de las siguientes opciones\n\t0 - Salir\n\t1 - No hacer nada\n\t2 - Dar de comer"
            + "\n\t3 - Dormir\n\t4 - Bañar\n\t5 - Jugar\n 6 - Pasear\n\t6 - Sacar a volar "); {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puees usar instance of

```
 String sacar="";
 Animal prueba = new Perro;

 if(prueba instanceof Perro)
     sacar="Sacar a Pasear";
 esle if(prueba instanceof Pajaro)
     sacar="sacar a Volar";
System.out.println("Bienvenido al Tamagotchi Estas en los años 90!!!!");
System.out.println("Escribe una de las siguientes opciones\n\t0 - Salir\n\t1 - No hacer nada\n\t2 - Dar de comer"
        + "\n\t3 - Dormir\n\t4 - Bañar\n\t5 - Jugar\n 6 - "+sacar;
```

No comprendo bien el uso de los tabulares eso correccionalo tu.
Espero te sea de ayuda.